# how to collect the result from worker node and print it in intellij?

Tags: apache-flink

My code is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Tf6xCdz4sz/)

I use this code in intellij,my step is:
①mvn clean
②mvn package
③run

This code is used for connecting to remote cluster with intellij.

the `print()` make the result saved in random taskmanager in random node in the cluster,

so I need to look for the result in $FLINK_HOME/log/*.out

Is there a way to collect these result and printed in intellij's console window?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the job within IntelliJ, using a local stream execution environment, e.g., via

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

rather than on a remote cluster, `print()` will shows its results in the console. But with a remote stream execution environment, the results will end up in the task managers' file systems, as you have noted.

I don't believe there is a convenient way to collect these results. Flink is designed around scalability, and thus the parallel sinks are designed to avoid any sort of bottleneck. Anything that will unify all of these output streams is a hindrance to scalability.

But what you could do, if you want to have all of the results show up in one place, would be to reduce the parallelism of the PrintSink to 1. This won't bring the results into IntelliJ, but it will mean that you'll find all of the output in one file, on one task manager. You would do that via

```java
.print()
.setParallelism(1)
```